# CSS HTML Cannot click on links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I have this page: http://highvision.vn/haisan/
and there are links on the left side, however I can't click on them.

Does anyone know why?

This is my CSS:

```
 .menu {
    background:url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:287px;
    height:492px;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -80px;
    padding: 55px 0 0 60px;


}
.menu div {
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-4deg);


}
.menu div {
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.menu div a {
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: 'Lobster', Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `<div class="pos-5">` and the wrapper element has a higher z-index than the other menu items. You need to set a higher z-index for the menu links (or make the elements not obscure the menu-links)

This CSS will put things in the right order:

```
.wrapper {
    z-index: 0;
}
.menu div {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: @TrungNguyen no problem! just set me up with some of that vietnamese food and were good ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove "**z-index**" in your class "**body**"

```
.body {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then add "**position**" and "**z-index**" to your "**.menu div**"

```
.menu div {
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have added a z-index of -1 to the div with the class "body".